# What tools and guide a beginner need to build a custom ROM for any device?

Tags: android, development-environment

I've searched it over on Google but not get any satisfied thread over XDA or anywhere else.
I'm a beginner and want to build my own custom ROM's at least for my device which I have own. I have little knowledge in C# so I think I can get understand the JAVA but not quite sure

So here is my question **What tools and guide I need to follow for make own custom ROM's**. Also If its possible I want to get them all for **offline** use as my bandwidth is very slow and I'm much depend on my friend to download the big contents. Any guide with detail would be appreciated.

Comment: "build a custom ROM" - can you explain what you mean by this term? Do you with to build everything from scratch (Linux, Drivers, Android framework, Core Apps, etc), or do you want to adjust an existing rom to fit your personal needs? If you're not sure, what is your motivation?

Comment: @dst I want to adjust an existing ROM to fit for my personal needs with some other mods and tweaking. Somehow for battery friendly and smooth one is my priority, and once again yes I want to modify the stock build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It varies. The easiest way to get started is download someone elses ROM and start by UNzipping it and extracting resources and playing with them. By doing this, you can start to modify resources. Then, as you want to modify certain aspects I would encourage you to look at particular tools.

The XDA university is a great place to get started. Here's a list of common things ROMs add and what you might consider (many of these items have open source variants you can port and modify to get familiar)

- [Custom kernels](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/adding-features-to-your-kernel)
- [Developer starter guide](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer)
- [Thememing APKs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1598829)

Comment: +1 seems good links, but can you tell me one more thing what IDE(most of the people recommend Eclipse) I should have to use for friendly interface. Also is there a way to stay away fro the tools from internet while I start my work as Eclipse need internet connection to add some packages.

Comment: @avirk Sure, download a ROM and extract it. A lot of APKs are just jars and can be extracted. So you can start themeing their resources. No specific tools required - just an archive. IDE wise, depends. Eclipse is a good candiate because you can use it for Java and C work (kernels). However, that's not to say you can't use something like Visual Studio for Kernel work if you're running Windows. (I prefer Visual Studio for the UI and nice toolset)

Comment: Wait you said VS, how can I use that? I have never heard that before for any android development?

Comment: You can use VS with MAKE tools and other stuff - so there's no reason you can't use VS. You just might meet more resistance. :)

Answer (score 1):

As you're wishing to modify an existing ROM, I'd recommend you grab a toolset like [dsixda's Android Kitchen](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=633246), which simplifies everyday-tasks like deodexing, extracting stuff from existing roms, etc. Also, if you have it you have most of the tools needed downloaded already, just look into the tools folder.

The only other Tool I'd recommend for getting started is [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/), which is capable of giving you low-level access on deodexed apk files. *Note:* If you have the source code of everything, you don't need this. However most stock roms are not completely open-sourced, so you need such tools to (manually) apply patches.

Both tools are no IDEs, and you can use any IDE to edit the stuff. However I doubt you can get a solid base without using some command-line tools ;) - if you only wish to change some ressources I guess there are easier ways.